# efficient way of Loading 6Million records from aws s3 to AuroraDB(cross account)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, nosql, aws-glue

I am trying to implement an ETL process which will load the data from s3 to AuroraDB(cross account).

I tried multiple approaches but failed

1. AWS datapipeline - After POC implementation, AWS team deprecating the services.. no meaning of going with that.
2. then opted for GLUE, GLUE is pathetic in performance as learnt from other teams it will days to process the data.
3. AWS Lambda - this has limitation with timeout (15 mins) to process the data.
4. Now i am thinking of alternatives to AuroraDB which can help do this super quick like noSQL.

looking forward for some suggestion within AWS limits to address this issue.

Comment: Have you looked into DMS? You could set up a DMS Replication Instance and one or more Data Migration Tasks set to full-load or full-load and ongoing to pull in your data. DMS supports S3 as a Source Endpoint for replication.

Comment: What I understood from DMS documentation, it makes it easy to pull data from non AWS systems into AWS but not sure on s3 end point. Any reference would be great

Comment: Here is a detailed document https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Source.S3.html